# issues with R "igraph" package neighbor function

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I started using the R "igraph" package recently(version 0.7). I wrote a simple program to understand the basics of the package(reading data into the graph object, getting the neighbours of a node). I am using a graph whose **vertices start at 0**. The edges in the graph are populated as I need it, however when I attempt to get the adjacency list/ neighbours of a node, I observed it was not giving the result that I expected. Can someone help me out with this/ or point out if I am missing something trivial ?

Below is the graph data/code that I wrote:

Graph Edge Data(first column contains the first vertex, second column contain the vertex to which there is an edge from the first vertex)

```
0 5
1 5
2 5
3 5
0 2

> library('igraph')
> graph_file_ori = read.table("test.txt")
> graph_obj = graph.data.frame(graph_file_ori,directed=FALSE)
> str(graph_obj)
IGRAPH UN-- 5 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):

[1] 0--5 1--5 2--5 3--5 0--2

> neighbors(graph_obj,0)
Error in .Call("R_igraph_neighbors", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph, v) - 1,  : 
At type_indexededgelist.c:750 : cannot get neighbors, Invalid vertex id
> neighbors(graph_obj,1)
[1] 3 5
> neighbors(graph_obj,2)
[1] 5
> neighbors(graph_obj,3)
[1] 1 5
> neighbors(graph_obj,4)
[1] 5
> neighbors(graph_obj,5)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Based on the graph, the expected output was :

```
neighbors(0) = 5,2
neighbors(1) = 5
neighbors(2) = 5,0
neighbors(3) = 5
```

Degree of 4 is 0.
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your graph has:
vertex 1: "0", vertex 2: "1", vertex 3: "2", vertex 4: "3", vertex 5: "5"

Here is how I think neighbors() works:

neighbors(graph_obj, 1) <=> neighbors(graph_obj, vertex 1) and it returns vertex 3, vertex 5 <=> "2" , "5"

neighbors(graph_obj, 2) <=> neighbors(graph_obj, vertex 2) and it returns vertex 5 <=> "5"

neighbors(graph_obj, 3) <=> neighbors(graph_obj, vertex 3) and it returns vertex 1, vertex 5 <=> "0" , "5"

...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use symbolic vertex names, that is fine, but then you need to use them in your queries as well. I.e. write

```
neighbors(graph_obj, "0")
```

If you want the results as symbolic names as well, then you need to do

```
graph_obj$name[neighbors(graph_obj, "0")]
```

This will be not needed from igraph version 0.8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this to get neighbors of vertex name "0". However, executing this i got the output as 3 5, when i expected it to be 2,5 or (3,6 assuming vertex id's start at 1). According to my understanding is because I do not have a vertex with name 4 defined in my graph. Is there any way to solve this issue ? Is there any way I can use vertex id's instead of vertex names ?